# Change XML Value of element with specific Attribute in Powershell

Tags: powershell

i just can't wrap my head around XML so please help me.

i have following small xml file

```
<OSDCollBuild>
  <Group Name="OSD">
    <Value key="1">1809</Value>
    <Value key="2">1909</Value>
    <Value key="3">1909.1</Value>
    <Value key="4">20H2</Value>
  </Group>
  <Group Name="Office">
    <Value key="1">Standard</Value>
    <Value key="2">Professional</Value>
    <Value key="3">Student</Value>
  </Group>
</OSDCollBuild>
```

now i want to change the Value of e.g. Group Name=OSD Value key=3 to lets say "1909.2"

but i do not how to tell Powerhsell to set inner text to THAT specific Element.
i have tryed to SelectSingleNode
and i get thet far

```
$xml.OSDCollBuild.Group.SelectSingleNode("//*[@Name='$Group'])
```

and now i don't now how to get further.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the following xPath to get the node with Group Name=OSD Value key=3:

`//OSDCollBuild/Group[@Name='OSD']/Value[@key='3']`

Here is a full example to change the text value:

```
$xml = [xml]@"
<OSDCollBuild>
  <Group Name="OSD">
    <Value key="1">1809</Value>
    <Value key="2">1909</Value>
    <Value key="3">1909.1</Value>
    <Value key="4">20H2</Value>
  </Group>
  <Group Name="Office">
    <Value key="1">Standard</Value>
    <Value key="2">Professional</Value>
    <Value key="3">Student</Value>
  </Group>
</OSDCollBuild>
"@

# find the node to change
$node = $xml.SelectSingleNode("//OSDCollBuild/Group[@Name='OSD']/Value[@key='3']")

# change the value
$node.InnerText = "1909.2"

# dump the xml to verify the change
$xml.OuterXml
```

Output:

```
<OSDCollBuild>
    <Group Name="OSD">
        <Value key="1">1809</Value>
        <Value key="2">1909</Value>
        <Value key="3">1909.2</Value>
        <Value key="4">20H2</Value>
    </Group>
    <Group Name="Office">
        <Value key="1">Standard</Value>
        <Value key="2">Professional</Value>
        <Value key="3">Student</Value>
    </Group>
</OSDCollBuild>
```

Comment: it looks like i almost had it myself at one point...

$element = $xml.OSDCollBuild.SelectSingleNode("//*[@Name='$Group']/Value[@Key='$myKey']")

Thank you very much :)